# Rails 3: How to sum multiple collection selections?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a select box collection called "Size", with values of 10, 25, 50, etc. I can add/remove this field using jquery so that, for example, there could be 3 different size selections on the page: 25, 50, and 10. If I want to sum up these values on this page, and get the total of 85, how can I accomplish this?

**audience.rb**

```
SIZE = ['5', '10', '25', '50', '75', '100']
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :audiences do |audience_form| %>
  <div class="audiencefields">
  <span class="audienceforminsert"></span>  
  <div>
    <%= audience_form.label :number_of_people, "Size" %><br />
    <%= audience_form.collection_select :number_of_people, Audience::SIZE, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
  </div>

  </div>

  <%= audience_form.link_to_remove "Remove this audience", :id => "removelink" %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add another audience", :audiences, :id => "addlink" %></p>
```

**application.js**

```
$("#removelink").hide().filter(":first-child").show();

$('form a.add_nested_fields, form a.remove_nested_fields').live('click', function(){
$("div.audiencefields span.audienceforminsert").each(function(index, element) {
    //index starts with 0
    $(this).text("Audience");});
});

$("span.audienceshowinsert").each(function(index, element) {
    //index starts with 0
    $(this).text("Audience " + (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: can you paste some code?

Answer (score 0):

Find all of the select boxes and add their selected value:

```
var combined = 0;
$("select").each(function() {
    combined += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Here is an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/DCLzG/).